# what to check if automatic failover does not work on always on availability group?

Tags: sql, alwayson

on one of my environment automatic failover does not work. what things i need to check, please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2833707/troubleshooting-automatic-failover-problems-in-sql-server-2012-alwayson-environments

> The symptoms when automatic failover is unsuccessful
>
> If an automatic failover event is not successful, the secondary
>   replica does not successfully transition to the primary role.
>   Therefore, the availability replica will report that this replica is
>   in Resolving status. Additionally, the availability databases report
>   that they are in Not Synchronizing status, and applications cannot
>   access these databases.
>
> For example, in the following image, SQL Server Management Studio
>   reports that the secondary replica is in Resolving status because the
>   automatic failover process was unable to transition the secondary
>   replica into the primary role:

Comment: i tried all these, not find any clues. is there any thing else need to check

Comment: review your checklist i'm pretty sure this is not unusual